# Figuring a max repetitive sub-tree in an object tree

Tags: algorithm, search, tree, similarity

I am trying to solve a problem of finding a max repetitive sub-tree in an object tree.

By the object tree I mean a tree where each leaf and node has a name. Each leaf has a type and a value of that type associated with that leaf. Each node has a set of leaves / nodes in certain order.

Given an object tree that - we know - has a repetitive sub-tree in it.

By repetitive I mean 2 or more sub-trees that are similar in everything (names/types/order of sub-elements) but the values of leaves. No nodes/leaves can be shared between sub-trees.

Problem is to identify these sub-trees of the max height.

I know that the exhaustive search can do the trick. I am rather looking for more efficient approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could implement a dfs traversal generating a hash value for each node. Store these values with the node height in a simple array. Sub-tree candidates are duplicate values, just check that the candidates are ok since two different sub-trees could yield same hash value.
Assuming the leafs and internal nodes are all of type Node and that standard access and traversal functions are available :

```
procedure dfs_update( node : Node, hashmap : Hashmap )
begin
  if is_leaf(node) then
    hashstring = concat("LEAF",'|',get_name_str(node),'|',get_type_str(node))
  else // node is an internal node
    hashstring = concat("NODE",'|',get_name_str(node))
    for each child in get_children_sorted(node)
      dfs_update(child,hashmap)
      hashstring = concat(hashstring,'|',get_hash_string(hashmap,child))
    end for
  end if
  // only a ref to node is added to the hashmap, we could also add
  // the node's height, hashstring, whatever could be useful and inapropriate
  // to keep in the Node ds
  add(hashmap, hash(hashstring),node)
end
```

The tricky part is after a `dfs_update`, we have to get the list of collinding nodes in the hasmap by descending height and check two by two they are really *repetitive*.

Comment: Nice, that should work. I am not marking this answered yet hoping to get more ideas.

Comment: Could you give an example of such a hash function? I would tend to this the hash function would be very difficult to implement.

Comment: Well, for leaves we could use any hash value for the string "LEAF|<NAME>|<TYPE>" and for internal nodes "NODE|<NAME>|<CHILD-1-HASH>|<CHILD-2-HASH>|....|<CHILD-LAST-HASH>".